# Get a array of values form a PLSQL Function

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I coded a function to select some flux in a queue and lock them with an updated flag.
I made it with a cursor and it worked great. But i need to get the ID of the flux i locked to process them in my application.

So i start to code a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function getIDArray
  RETURN VARCHAR2 is
  arr varchar2(1000);

          CURSOR flux_to_process                                                          
          IS                                                                              
           SELECT  FLUX_ID, LOCKED_FLAG
           FROM (
               SELECT FLUX_ID, FLUX, GROUP_STORE_ID, STORE_ID, REFID, FLUX_TYPE, LOCKED_FLAG
                 FROM DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                      
                 WHERE status = 0                                                           
                 AND LOCKED_FLAG = 0                                                                                                             
                 ORDER BY DATE_CREATION ASC)
            WHERE ROWNUM <= 8;

          BEGIN                                                                           

          FOR flux_rec IN flux_to_process                                                 
              LOOP                                                                        
              IF flux_rec.LOCKED_FLAG = 0
                THEN      

                UPDATE DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                    
                SET LOCKED_FLAG = 1                                                         
                WHERE FLUX_ID = flux_rec.FLUX_ID; 
                arr := flux_rec.FLUX_ID;

              else exit;
          COMMIT;                                                                         
          END IF;
          END LOOP; 
          RETURN arr;
         END;
```

The function compilation return an OK but i got no return of my values.

Do you guys have any clue to how to do this ?

Comment: Why do you use a cursor and loop if your cursor query only returns only one row? (`WHERE ROWNUM <= 1`)

Comment: Because it can return more than 1 row, actually it's a variable in my application. i edited the question :)

Comment: @angezanetti Maybe I am wrong, but at first sight all of this seems over-complicated for a simple task. Can't you do all that job using only one request `UPDATE ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...) RETURNING ... BLUK COLLECT INTO ...` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm#CJAGFGDE)

Comment: My best guess is that the cursor is returning no data. Try running the  cursor SQL in SQL*Plus or something similar. Best of luck.

Comment: Reason should be `exit` keyword, i suggest you remove the else part, because if in your first `flux_rec` the `flux_rec.LOCKED_FLAG <> 0 `then the program will exit without results.

Comment: @Aramillo This part of the code was puzzling me. How could be `flux_rec.LOCKED_FLAG <> 0` as it is explicitly requested in the cursor `WHERE ... AND LOCKED_FLAG = 0` ?

Comment: Yes @SylvainLeroux you are right, i didn't see that, this part of the code is not necessary, and  of course the else part never occurs.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yeah seems legit :) This request is the end of a loong process which started with a select for update, that's why i used a cursor

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your issue per se, the only two reasons I can see for the function to return "no value" would be either:

- the `SELECT` part returns an *empty* set,
- you have one record where `FLUX_ID` is `NULL`.

For improbable that could be that later option given the name of the column, it would be rather coherent with the fact that you override the result at each iteration -- and the `ORDER BY` orders `NULL` after not-`NULL` by default.

Comment: The select returns 8 values, `FLUX_ID` is never NULL... i rewrited the request here (The update works fine) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836393/return-values-of-update-request-plsql