# Return values of update request PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

*This question is related to [Get a array of values form a PLSQL Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824246/get-a-array-of-values-form-a-plsql-function) .*

---

I got a update request which works great. But i would like to get an array of the `FLUX_ID` the request just updated the `LOCKED_FLAG`

```
CREATE TYPE arr_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE Function getIDArray
RETURN arr_t is
arr arr_t;

BEGIN

UPDATE DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                    
SET LOCKED_FLAG = 1                                                         
WHERE FLUX_ID IN (
SELECT  FLUX_ID
FROM (
 SELECT FLUX_ID, FLUX, GROUP_STORE_ID, STORE_ID, REFID, FLUX_TYPE, LOCKED_FLAG
 FROM DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                      
 WHERE status = 0                                                           
 AND LOCKED_FLAG = 0                                                                                                             
 ORDER BY DATE_CREATION ASC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 8)

RETURNING FLUX_ID BULK COLLECT INTO arr;

return arr;
END;
/
```

**EDIT** Update the code with the answer of Sylvain. But this request do not return anything, and don't update the table.
NB: I just re-tested the update statement, it works fine (update the flag to 1)

Do you have a clue of how i should do this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I guess OP is pointing to the link he posted on top of his question. It has a function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name More specifically, I think the question is about adding the `RETURNING ... BULK COLLECT INTO` clause when using such statement in a PL/SQL block as it was suggested in a comment on the _other_ question. Yet, it would be better for the OP if he could edit this question himself to explain that clearly.

Comment: Nothing will happen when you compile the function; you need to call it from somewhere. Though it should probably be a procedure rather than a function as it's doing work, with an `out` parameter if you need the caller to process the affected IDs. You haven't said where you are using this or what you want to do with the returned IDs though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah true, first step was to code the request. Then i need to use it! Actually it's a part of a PHP application, i would like to retrieve the IDs as an array to start some process on each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that maybe ?

```
CREATE TYPE arr_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE Function getIDArray
RETURN arr_t is
  arr arr_t;

BEGIN
  -- all your update statement (I assume this part is OK)
  UPDATE DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                    
  SET LOCKED_FLAG = 1                                                         
  WHERE FLUX_ID IN (
   SELECT  FLUX_ID
   FROM (
     SELECT FLUX_ID, FLUX, GROUP_STORE_ID, STORE_ID, REFID, FLUX_TYPE, LOCKED_FLAG
     FROM DEV_ISB_TRANSACTIONS.BUFFER_FLUX                                      
     WHERE status = 0                                                           
     AND LOCKED_FLAG = 0                                                                                                             
     ORDER BY DATE_CREATION ASC)
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 8)
  -- continuing (no ';' !!!) with the returning clause:    
  RETURNING FLUX_ID BULK COLLECT INTO arr;

  return arr;
END;
/
```

Please note the `RETURNING ...`is a *clause* of the `UPDATE` statement. **You shall not break that statement by addinga semi-colon `;` in the middle**.  Would you add such `;` say after `select` and before `where` ? Of course no...

And about using it:

```
declare
 result arr_t;
begin
  result := getIDArray();
  for i in 1 .. result.COUNT
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(result(i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: I got a syntax error on the `RETURNING FLUX_ID BULK COLLECT INTO arr;
` SQLdevelopper says:  Encountered `FLUX_ID` when expecting one of the following: ;
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: @angezanetti Assuming your update statement is OK, there shouldn't be such error on the `RETURNING ...` clause. Did you let the `;` by mistake after `WHERE ROWNUM <= 8)` ? Which version of Oracle are you using ? _If_ I remember it well, `BULK COLLECT` was added in _10g_ ...

Comment: I updated the question with the latest version of the code, still get the syntax error

Comment: @angezanetti ... and you didn't read carefully my first comment ;)

Comment: @angezanetti **don't put a semi-colon** before `RETURNING INTO...`. This is part of the statement.

Comment: Yeah i miss read your comment ! I still get a compilation error: Symbol 'CREATE' encounter on line 3

Comment: @angezanetti - if you're running this as shown as a script, you need a `/` after the `create type` statement; otherwise the whole thing is treated as one command.

Comment: Yeah works better with the `/` ! Still get some error tho: 

`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “end-of-file” when expecting one of the following` on line 23

Comment: @angezanetti - you need a `/` after the function creation too - this is basic stuff about how PL/SQL blocks work... [This compiles on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54a58/1).

Comment: Ok, now i get no error in SQL developper \o/ But it does not update the value and return anything :/. THe return are just `TYPE ARR_T compiled` & `FUNCTION GETIDARRAY compiled`

Comment: @angezanetti - so... you didn't call the function yet? You can't just call it from a select statement though as the function does DML. Maybe you should edit the question to show how you plan to call this and use the returned values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the [RETURNING INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause. The `DML` which manipulates the data would return as `OUT` into a variable or collection.

Note : I don't have your table and data, so an example of EMP table in SCOTT schema -

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    V_NM EMP.ENAME%TYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4    UPDATE EMP SET EMPNO = 10
  5    WHERE EMPNO = 7369
  6    RETURNING ENAME INTO V_NM;
  7    COMMIT;
  8
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('NAME=' || V_NM);
 10  END;
 11  /
NAME=SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**EDIT** Above example was too simple. In your case, to get the list of all `FLUX_ID`, you need `BULK COLLECT` and `collection`.

Consider this example, where I get the list of all employee names which have been updated.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF emp.ename%TYPE;
  3    l_tab t_tab;
  4  BEGIN
  5    UPDATE emp
  6    SET    sal = 1000
  7    RETURNING ename BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;
  8
  9    FOR i IN 1..l_tab.count
 10      LOOP
 11         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UPDATED ENAME=' || l_tab(i));
 12    END LOOP;
 13
 14  END;
 15  /
UPDATED ENAME=SMITH
UPDATED ENAME=ALLEN
UPDATED ENAME=WARD
UPDATED ENAME=JONES
UPDATED ENAME=MARTIN
UPDATED ENAME=BLAKE
UPDATED ENAME=CLARK
UPDATED ENAME=SCOTT
UPDATED ENAME=KING
UPDATED ENAME=TURNER
UPDATED ENAME=ADAMS
UPDATED ENAME=JAMES
UPDATED ENAME=FORD
UPDATED ENAME=MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I edited the question with your way, but it doesn't works. I get a syntax error (see me comment to sylvain below)

Comment: Seems like you did not put the forward slash `/` in the end of the function.